# How to set email alias in Evolution client

Tags: email, gmail, evolution

I have a gmail account registered as business account (**my.name@yyyy.com**), this business account has got an alias, if I send a mail from gmail.com site, my email address will be ***my.name@xxxx.com***.

How can I do the same thing in Evolution client?
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

In Evolution:

1. *Edit* then *Preferences* or use the shortcut `Shift + Control + S`.
2. Click on *Mail Accounts*.
3. Select the one you want to add the alias to.
4. Click *Edit*.
5. In the *Identity* tab find the *Aliases* box, should be the last.
6. Add the email alias.

#### Addendum: Making the alias the default

I found [this](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2016-June/msg00082.html) thread helpful. In summary, I had to add my alias as my *Email Address* and my address as my *Alias*.

P.S. I know this comes late, but I run into this open question while searching for its solution.